# How to find the limit of an infinite sum

Tags: limits, summation, limits-without-lhopital

I was curious the other day about a limit that I could not figure out the answer to. The limit went somewhat like this: $$\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}( \frac{ln(x)}{k^2}+3^k)$$ My question is more about how to find the limit of this summation then to actually solve this summation. I know this exact summation of this limit is infinity but I want to know how to find the limit for other sums that don't go to infinity. And if this question is unclear be free to ask me or edit the question because I am new to this community don't want to have questions that are not good.

Sorry for editing the problem to much I was just trying to make it more clear but made it more complicated. I restored the actual problem so the answers would make sense.

Thanks to anyone that answers my problem!

Comment: You keep using the word, *equation*. It doesn't mean what you think it means. [Hint: an equation requires an "equals sign".]

Comment: $$\sum _{k=1}^N \left(\ln \left(\frac{x}{k^2}\right)+3^k\right)=-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3^{1+N}}{2}+\ln
   \left(\frac{x^N}{(N!)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Is there a typo in your sum? Otherwise, the $1$ there doesn't make sense.

Comment: Concerning your general question. There is not a general method or algorithm to calculate the sum of infinite series.

Comment: yes the 1 was a typo

Comment: I also changed the question to make it easier to read

Comment: You've got a completely different series to what you started with. Please work out what you want to ask before you post it. Otherwise, the page just becomes a mess, as has happened here.

Comment: Ok I am a new user I am trying to learn how to ask a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^N3^k=\frac{3(1-3^N)}{1-3}=\frac{3}{2}(3^N-1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^Nln(\frac{1}{k^2})=ln(\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k^2})=ln(\frac{1}{(N!)^2})=-2ln(N!)$$
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N(3^k+ln(\frac{1}{k^2}))=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}-2ln(N!)-\frac{2}{3})$$
Also,
$$2ln(N!)<2ln(N^N)=2NlnN<2N^2$$ for all $N>=1$

Meanwhile, $\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}$ is exponential and $2N^2$ is quadratic, so
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}-2N^2)=\infty$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N(3^k+ln(\frac{1}{k^2}))=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}-2ln(N!)-\frac{2}{3})=\infty$$