# How to Rewrite Sums $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N}$

Tags: limits

## Simplifying Sums

#### Original question with answer:

I asked another question on math stack exchange about an infinite sum. Here is the question if any of you want to look at it: [How to find the limit of an infinite sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821139/how-to-find-the-limit-of-an-infinite-sum)

The question was to find the limit of the sum:
$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left({\ln(\frac{x}{k^2})}+3^k\right)$$

One of the answers *(by user **YANGyu**)* said that:

> 

$$\sum_{k=1}^N3^k=\frac{3(1-3^N)}{1-3}=\frac{3}{2}(3^N-1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\ln\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{k^2})\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{(N!)^2}\right)=-2\ln(N!)$$
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(3^k+\ln\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}-2\ln(N!)-\frac{2}{3}\right)$$
Also,
$$2\ln(N!)<2\ln(N^N)=2N\ln N<2N^2$$ for all $N>=1$

Meanwhile, $\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}$ is exponential and $2N^2$ is quadratic, so
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}-2N^2)=\infty$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(3^k+\ln\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\right)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{3^{N+1}}{2}-2\ln(N!)-\frac{2}{3}\right)=\infty$$

> 

It seemed he simplified the sum to make it easier to work with. My question is mainly about how he simplified the sum. This would be helpful for other problems dealing with sums like this one.

#### Questions about YANGyu's solution:

- I am curious to how he got to the simplified sum so I can solve other problems like this.
- I am curious if there are any other ways to simplify different expressions because the two expressions that were simplified above were ln(k) and 3<sup>k</sup>. It would be helpful if someone could list the different techniques for simplifying sums.

##### How could I make this question better

Please comment on how I could improve this question if it is unclear. This is important to me so in the future I can ask better questions. This is also important so that if anyone finds this post trying to figure out the same thing I am they will understand what I am talking about.

Comment: It helps to organize the site better if you only ask one question per post :) Your question about clarification of the answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821139/how-to-find-the-limit-of-an-infinite-sum) is better suited to comments on that original post. And as to your question about the different ways to simplify expressions/solve series, there is unfortunately no simple answer. There are thousands of tactics but no general method, and sometimes no solution at all. It's far too much to put into a single post as it comprises a whole field of math.

Comment: Thank you jam that helps me ask better questions in the future. Also thank you for clarifying that there is no method to simplify sums.

Comment: There's no need to simplify the whole sum. You can just look at the summands. Note $\ln(x) /k^2 \geq 0$ (if $\ln x \geq 0$) and $\ln(x) / k^2 \geq \ln(x)$ (if $\ln(x) < 0$). So $\frac{\ln(x)}{k^2}+3^k \geq \max(0,\ln(x)) + 3^k$ which is unbounded as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Actually there seems to be some confusion here, are we talking about $\ln(x) / k^2$ or $\ln (1/k^2)$?

Comment: We are talking about  ln(x)/k^2

Comment: And it is less about this specific summation and more about summations that go to a finite value. For example $$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{1+22n}-\frac{1}{2+22x}\right)$$

Comment: I think the answer in the other question was for an earlier edit and interpreted it to be about $\ln(x/k^2)$. If the $k^2$ is outside the log the question is very different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150162/discussion-between-alex-beam-and-jair-taylor).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**$$\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$$So for $N$ terms: $$\sum_{n=1}^N\log(a_n)=\log\left(\prod_{n=1}^Na_n\right)$$